# Am I using IR2104 correctly?

Tags: mosfet, audio, class-d

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flYUX6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
I am using the following circuit with given component values.
I am not getting a proper level of output from Ho or Lo pin to drive the MOSFETs. The voltage level is in mV. Also, the square waveform that I should be getting from Ho and Lo pin is not very crisp.
I have not connected the load yet.
This circuit is being used for Class D Audio Amplifier.
Any suggestion why the the Driver IC2104 is not working?

Comment: We're not going to read your netlist and draw it. Edit your question using the schematic button somewhere in the middle of the top bar. Also, please be so polite as to review what it looks like before you press submit. This needs more enters.

Comment: Please add a schematic. You can add a schematic via the built-in schematic editor in the post editor.

Comment: Originally you said "Ho pin output is varying from +4.4V to -4.4V and Lo pin output is varying from +5 to -5.". This make no sense (the IR2104 cannot generate negative voltages). Please make sure the scope inputs are set to **DC**, and show us the waveforms at HO, LO, and Vs. Also check that your FETs are connected correctly.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, that was an error, which I tried to rectify today but ended up getting output in mV instead. I have connected the MOSFET exactly as shown in the schematic that I have provided.    The outputs from Ho and Lo are not very crisp square wave, plus they are in millivolts.

Comment: Your circuit is drawn technically correct, but it suggests that the IC ground may actually be different than the MOSFET/power supply ground... please confirm that the COM pin, power supply, and M2 source are all connected together.

Comment: @slightlynybbled I did connect the grounds of all these together. Double-triple checked.

Comment: Remove the FETs and look at LO - you should get a square wave going from 0V to Vcc. If not then you are not providing correct voltages (Vcc must be >=10V), or the IR2104 is wired incorrectly, or it is blown up. If you get the correct waveform then the FET is blown.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I did try this. Removed the FETs and measured Lo, it was square wave but in mV. I supplied a 12V supply go IC

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I could see square wave output at both Lo and Ho but both in mV range

Comment: You are sure that the output was only 'mV' and all the input voltages/signals were correct? Then the IR2104 is blown up.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes. Very sure. The output was in mV. The PWM wave was somewhere near +-5V. The voltage supply to IC 2104 was 12V. The voltage supply to upper MOSFET was 8V while lower one was grounded. Are all these correct?

Comment: PWM wave should be 0v to +5V, **not** -5V!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Oh! Should I clamp my PWM signal to a positive value then?

Comment: Yes. It may be too late though, because the absolute maximum rating (beyond which damage to the device may occur) is Min. -0.3V.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I was wondering why the IC is getting heated so much. Luckily I bought 2 IC from the market so I will try on the other one. Wasted 3$ but! :/

Answer (score 1):

1. As Mario states, you must use a large enough capacitor.  I generally use a 1uF to 4.7uF 0805 ceramic capacitor for this bootstrap capacitor.
2. Check your diode polarity.  It is correct in the schematic, but it is one of the easiest things to mess up in this circuit.
3. Additionally, you MUST continually 'toggle' the capacitor, meaning that the lower MOSFET *MUST* be periodically turned on in order to refresh the charge across the bootstrap cap.  If you leave the upper MOSFET on for too long, the capacitor voltage will begin to droop and your FET will move into the linear region.  Try driving with a square wave of at least 20kHz.

Comment: 1. I will definitely try with large capacitor.      2. The diode polarity is correct, I am 100% sure as I have been working on this circuit for 6 straight hours.     3. How do I toggle the capacitor? Will that be automatic or do I have to introduce any change in the circuit?

Comment: Toggle the input to your IC at a frequency.  Use a 20kHz square wave on your 'IN' pin.  In order to refresh the charge on Cboot, the output MUST be toggled periodically.

Comment: I did try with square wave as well, varied it from 50Hz to some 100s of Hz.      2. How do I ensure that output is getting toggled as you said?

Comment: That is your problem, 50Hz is WAAAAYYYY too slow :)... so is 100s of Hz.... you need to be in the 10000s

Comment: I tried 50Hz only because it wasn't working in KHzs. Initially I was working in some 50-60kHz range

Comment: Your bootstrap capacitor has a certain amount of charge on it.  When you turn on the upper MOSFET, that charge bleeds on to the gate.  As you leave the upper MOSFET on, the charge continues to droop.  When you are operating at a low frequency, the charge on the capacitor simply droops too much.

Comment: You may have gone the wrong direction.  It will NOT work in the lower frequency range, I can guarantee that.

Comment: Actually, there is no reason why it shouldn't work with a frequency as low as 10Hz.

Comment: To ensure that the output is toggling, place an oscillocope probe between the two MOSFETs, referenced to your ground.  That point between the MOSFETs should reflect your input waveform.

Comment: @Mario You are correct, if the bootstrap cap is appropriately sized.  He has a very small capacitor...

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor C1 needs to provide the gate charge for the MOS transistor. A 100nF capacitor is too small. Try something in the order of 10uF.

It is also required to switch M2 first, otherwise C1 can't get charged. Depending on the application a startup circuit could be required.

Comment: I tried with different capacitors. In fact I connected a decade capacitance box and varies it with all possible value. The circuit still doesnt seem to work

Comment: That adds a lot of inductance, too. Use a 10uF cap.

Comment: I have tried till 1uF electrolytic capacitors. I will try with 10uF as well. Is there anything else that could possibly go wrong in the above circuit?

Comment: You need to make sure that M2 switches first in order to charge C1. Then you should use an additional capacitor between VCC and COM.

Comment: How do I ensure that M2 switches first? Do I have to introduce some changes in the circuit?   2. What should be the value of capacitor between Vcc and COM?

Comment: You have to provide an input signal that switches M2. Use a 100nF capacitor and depending on your supply maybe another 10uF in parallel.

Comment: How do I ensure that my signal switches M2 first?  Because input signal is a PWM which I am giving at 'IN' pin.       2. The 100nF and 10uF that you suggested to connect, where should I connect them?

Comment: Then M2 will switch anyway, so eveything is OK.

Comment: Okay. I don't really know then what went possibly wrong there

Comment: @AnkitSahay he is suggesting that you connect the 100nF and 10uF capacitors in the C1 slot.

Comment: @slightlynybbled Okay. I already tried with 100nF. I will try with 10uF as well. Is it all then? Could anything else go wrong?

Comment: @AnkitSahay Without actually being in the room with you, I believe that this is all the help you can get.  There are lots of good suggestions on this page.  Ultimately, it will be something simple, so if you find yourself going down a very complex road, then stop, grab some coffee, and come back to it in 10.

Comment: @slightlynybbled I understand. Thank you so much for guiding me you wonderful people. It's weekend coming up so can't go to Labs for next two days. Will try to look into it theoretically as much as I can in these two days and will head to Labs on Monday again. Once again, thank you so much everyone.